# Is this circumstance, is it better to use an SSIS package, or just script out the job?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

Forewarning: I wasn't entirely sure if this question should be in here (SO) or in The Workplace because it isn't so much about programming, as much as it is convincing my co-worker that I think their method is bad. But it's still programming related. So MODs, please feel free to relocate this question to 'the workplace'. Anyway...

At work we have large SSAS cubes that have been split into multiple partitions. The individual who set up these partitions scheduled every partition to be processed everyday. But in hindsight because the data in these partitions is historic there is no need to process each partition everyday. Only the current partition should be processed after the latest data has been added into the cube's data source.

I gave my coworker a task to automate this process. I figured all they need to do is get the current date, and then process the partition corresponding to that date range. Easily scriptable.

My coworker creates an SSIS package for doing this...

Cons:

- the ssis package is hard to source control
- the ssis package will be hard to test
- the ssis package is a pain in the ass to debug
- the ssis package requires Visual Studio and Visual Studio Data Tools to even open
- lastly, I feel SSIS packages lead to heavy technical-debt

Pros:

- it's easier for my coworker to do (maybe)

Correct me if I'm wrong on any of those but just the first reason is enough for me to scrap all of their work.

Needless to say I'm extremely biased against anything done in SSIS. But processing a cube can be scripted out in `xmla` (ref: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/schedule-ssas-administrative-tasks-with-sql-server-agent)). And then using a SQL Server Agent job you can schedule that script to run a specific times. The only tricky part would be changing out the *partition name* that is processed within the script. Furthermore, the script/job can be kept in source control and then deployed to the MSSQL server whenever a change is made.

Am I being too critical here? I'm just trying to keep the next developers from ripping their hair out.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have two SQL Jobs:

1) Full processing + repartitioning

2) Incremental processing (processing of only last (current) partition).

You don't need SSIS neither for (1), nor for (2).

For (2) the script will be fixed - you just make a call to process one partition and incremental processing of dimensions (if required). Current partition must have a condition WHERE  >= ....     (not BETWEEN), so it covers the future dates if a new partition is not created yet.

For (1), you can write TSQL code that creates a new partition for the new period and reprocess the cube. It can be scheduled to run over weekend when the server is idle, or once per month.

(1) does below:

- backup existing cube (Prod) via SSAS Command of SQL Agent
- restore the backup as TempCube  via SSAS Command of SQL Agent with AllowOverwrite (in case if temp cube was not deleted before)
- delete all partitions in TempCube via TSQL + LinkedServer to SSAS
- re-create partitions and process cube (full) via TSQL +LinkedServer to SSAS
- Backup TempCube
- Delete TempCube
- Restore backup of TempCube as Production Cube.

As you see, the process is crash safe and you don't need SSIS. Even when a job (that creates a new partition) wasn't run for some reason, the cube still have the new data. The data will be split when a new partition structure is created by (1).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this wrong way. To be honest your list of cons is pretty bad and is just a reflection of your opinion of SSIS. There is always more than one tool in the toolbox for any job. The proper tool to use will vary from shop to shop.

If the skill set of the party responsible for development and maintenance of this automated process is SSIS then you should really have a better reason than personal preference to rewrite the process with a different tool. A couple reasons I can think of are company standards and skill set of the team.

If company standard dictates the tool then follow that. You should have staff that are capable of using the tools the company mandates. Otherwise assess the skill set of your team. If you have a team of SSIS developers don't force them to use something else because its your personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Your task of dynamic SSAS partitions processing can be automated with or without SSIS. SSIS is just an environment to execute tasks and do data manipulation. On its Pros - it has built-in components which execute XMLA script from variable and capture error messages. In pure .NET you have to do it yourself, but it is not too complex.

Several sample approaches to your task

- [Create XMLA XML and execute it with SSIS](https://bennyaustin.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/dynamic-processing/).
- [Generate XMLA from AMO library and execute it in .NET](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2014/05/how-to-automate-ssas-cube-partitioning-in-ssis/). You need to look at chapter **4d) Process All Dims**. Provided sample does more that that and steps are put into SSIS package as well.

I personally used SSIS in similar situation, probably because the other 99% of ETL logic and data manipulation is on SSIS. As said before, SSIS offers no significant advantage here. The second example shows how to do it in pure .NET.